# Pseudo Random Generator (PRG) not deterministic

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

Usually a Pseudo Random Generator is supposed to be IND-CPA secure.

But apparently, it is not in some cases such as the following:

- A PseudoRandom Generator $G$ has expansion factor $n + 2$.
- Encrypt $m \space \in \{0,1\} ^ {n+2}$
- Choose a random value $v \leftarrow \{0,1\}^n$
- Then send $(v, G(v) \oplus m)$

The question is why is it not IND-CPA secure and also not IND-EAV secure?

Comment: Sorry, this is probably me, but doesn't have a PRG just have a single input: the seed? I presume we are talking about some stream cipher or PRF here? Otherwise, how can IND-CPA even apply?

Comment: IND-CPA is a property of encryption schemes, not of PRGs.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Acronym mix-up? A PRG (which is different from a PRNG) uses a key and one other input.

Comment: OK, in that case Wikipedia on PRG seems *way* off. That might be just Wikipedia though. Alternatively, the cipher *based on* the PRG called $G$ may not be IND-CPA secure? In that case, what happens if $n=0$ or $n=1$?